Do ESP32 GPIO pins with roles such as 'BOOT' affect my program?
I am working with an ESP32-C-DeVKitC-02. I do flash it via USB:

There are pins with roles such as LOG or BOOT. Will they affect my program (I use Arduino IDE) or do I need to consider these flags, if I use these pins for input and output? I do drive transistors and MOSFETs with it, I don't want the ESP32 to trigger something I don't want during boot phase or so.
How can I make sure my program doesn't do anything as long the boot phase is not finished?

Technically no, the boot mode control straps don't affect your program.
They affect how the chip boots.
So if the boot control straps are set to boot your program normally, your program runs. If the boot control straps are used to boot something else than your program, then it won't run your program, but boots some other program that makes it do something else, like wait firmware upload from UART or USB.
And those pins are set by your hardware. If you e.g. have a BJT transistor controlling a relay on some boot mode control pin like GPIO9, there are two problems. The chip boots and checks for the pin value. It checks this by enabling an internal pull-up resistor. Because there is a transistor on that pin, the transistor keeps the pin pulled low, and the ESP32 will not run your program, but the bootloader.
A secondary problem is that since the ESP32 enables the internal pull-up, it may turn the transitor on, which in turn may turn some load like a relay on, and the relay might control something dangerous like a mains powered heater or motor or whatever that should not run until the software knows if it's cold enough or the motor is not driven to an endstop already.
So it's basically the opposite, your hardware should be designed not to interfere with the built-in boot/software features of the chip, or to not get interfered by the chip built-in boot/software features.
As soon as your program runs, you can generally do anything with the IO pins you want. Except things that take long to reset to default state, such as capacitors on boot strap pins.

Thank you! You say, that the Hardware should be designed not to interfere; but doesn't that mean in reality that some pins can only be pulled-down or up, but I can't decide? Maybe something for an extra question, but that sounds complex.

@Tintenfisch Yes, it's that simple, these are pins you are not free to use them as you wish, i.e. deliberately or accidentally set to wrong state, or connect these to some sensors with unknown state, or connect to some actuator as it may be actuated before your code runs.
